A proof of ZMT in Liu's "Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves"
I'm reading the proof of Zariski's main theorem (ZMT) in Liu's "Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves"

In the third sentence there is a claim about existence of an integral projective scheme $Z$. I don't see why such scheme exists. Does it follow from some other fact in that book?
After some thinking and discussion in comments I come to a conclusion that there is a missing condition in the theorem: $X$ has to be integral.

This explains existence of integral $Z$ in the proof.
We need to use 4.2 via 4.3 and for this we need $X$ to be integral.
Most importantly, the notion of birational morphism is only defined (at least in this book) between integral schemes.


I had this problem often reading the book. Similarly with Hartshorne. Steeped in mystery

This looks like Chow's lemma. Does Liu cover that at all?

There is Chow's lemma without a proof on the p. 109 (remark 3.34). But Chow's lemma relate proper and projective morphisms, I don't see how it is helpful here.

Isn't this simple because $U\to Y$ is affine, so quasi-projective? Like see https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0B42 Don't you just want to embed $U$ into a relative affine space over $Y$ then take the closure in some projective space? Of course you need to be mildly careful as you want $Z$ to be integral but, assuming $U$ is integral (which I assume you can reduce to -- and is being implicitly assumed by Liu) you can always finagle this -- look at any open embedding into a relatively projective thing, then take the closure with the reduced structure,

it will still be relatively projective but now it will be reduced (by set up) and irreducible (as $U$ is).

Yes, I was thinking in this direction too, but I wasn't able to find a convincing argument that it is enough to consider integral/irreducible $U$.
